# How to obtain the browser's download location using Node JS?

Tags: node.js

I need to transfer files from one location to another, and the destination folder should be the user's *download* location.

I was wondering if it's possible to obtain the browser's *download* location using Node JS or simply Javascript. I need a way to do it that works for all systems and browsers possibly.

Up to now I was just typing the location manually, but I need an automatised way of doing it of course!

Answer (score 3):

At least on Windows, this will normally be `%USERPROFILE%/Downloads`.

In NodeJS, you could write:
`var downloadFolder = process.env.USERPROFILE + "/Downloads";`

Comment: `USERPROFILE` gives me undefined, but I checked the properties of `env` and apparently there's `USER` and `HOME`. Maybe it has changed from one version to the other of NodeJS. Anyway, this could be a workaround, but the download location could not be under `Downloads` even on Windows...

Comment: Uer can can change the browser's download location, so this method maybe not work.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible in node.js to know the user's download location unless you ask the user to specifically type it into some input field in a form.  That location is purely a user agent setting that is purposely not disclosed to any server or web page for security reasons.

Furthermore, the server or webpage cannot influence where a file might be saved by the browser on the user's local hard drive anyway (again for security reasons) so there's nothing useful a server can do with that information anyway unless you happen to be running a server that is on the same machine as the browser.  If you're working in that type of controlled environment, then perhaps you could use a browser extension that does have access to some of these kinds of things.